# How to have npm run <script> delegate to child package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I've got 2 levels of `package.json` files.

Example is here:

https://github.com/justin808/react-webpack-rails-tutorial

The reason is that the top level is a Rails App, and I'm putting all node tools under a directory called client, with it's own `package.json` file. The top level `package.json` file is a convenience as well as a hook for the node buildpack to run the `npm install` script.

I've got an example of forwarding the `gulp` command. Any way to generically forward anything not found from the top level `package.json` to the child one?

Top Level `package.json`.

```
{
  "name": "react-webpack-rails-tutorial",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "Code from the React Webpack tutorial.",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.32"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd ./client && npm install",
    "gulp": "cd ./client && npm run gulp"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/justin808/react-webpack-rails-tutorial.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "tutorial",
    "comment",
    "example"
  ],
  "author": "justin808",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/justin808/react-webpack-rails-tutorial/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/justin808/react-webpack-rails-tutorial"
}
```

Subdirectory `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "react-webpack-rails-tutorial",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "Code from the React Webpack tutorial.",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.32"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/justin808/react-webpack-rails-tutorial.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "tutorial",
    "comment",
    "example"
  ],
  "author": "justin808",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/justin808/react-webpack-rails-tutorial/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/justin808/react-webpack-rails-tutorial",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^5.0.8",
    "babel-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.12.2",
    "es5-shim": "^4.1.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "jquery": "^2.1.3",
    "loader-utils": "^0.2.6",
    "marked": "^0.3.3",
    "react": "^0.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.20.1",
    "sleep": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.7.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^2.0.2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.4",
    "bootstrap-sass-loader": "^1.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.9.1",
    "eslint": "^0.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^2.0.2",
    "expose-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "express": "^4.12.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "gulp-eslint": "^0.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^2.1.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.4",
    "sass-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "gulp": "gulp"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

You can use `npm run` scripts to simplify the transaction (see [npm-scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)). In the parent `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
      ...
     "client-build": "cd client && npm run build"
   }
```

Where the client has a `package.json` with the `npm run build` command for building the client-side code.

Then invoke `npm run client-build` as part of the shell command of other tasks. For instance:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run client-build && gulp some-task", 
     ...
   }
```

It may help to break the child project out into a separate module with its own git repo and building it through a postinstall script. In that case, when running `npm install` on the parent project, the child will have a chance to build itself.

Answer (score -1):

> you could write a batch file where you put the `gulp`-command. Then you have to check the errorstate. That could look like this:

```
@echo off

:RUN_GULP
echo Running Gulp...
gulp
goto END

:END
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto PROCESS_ERROR
exit

:PROCESS_ERROR
cd ./client
gulp
exit;
```

> Then you just have to call the script in your package.json like this:

```
"gulp": "call ./path/to/batfile.bat"
```

Did the same on my project....

> EDIT: For all scripts.... you could create one batchfile that takes the script name as parameter. the script does the same like above, but it should work for every command.
>
> NOTE: You have to use something like `start path/to/batchfile.bat gulp` instead of `npm run gulp`. Errorhandling do not work for npm errors!

This could look like this:

```
@echo off

:: Check if script is defined
set _script=%1
if "%_script%"=="" goto NO_SCRIPT_DEFINED

:START_APP
npm run %_script%
goto END

:NO_SCRIPT_DEFINED
echo ERROR: script was not defined
pause
exit

:END
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto NO_PARENT_SCRIPT
exit

:NO_PARENT_SCRIPT
echo searching in ./client ...
cd ./client 
npm run %_script%
exit
```